# In compact Hausdorff spaces closed sets with $K_{n+1} \subseteq K_{n}$. Then $\cap K_{n}$ is non empty.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and for $n=1,2, \cdots, K_{n}$ be nonempty closed subsets with $K_{n+1} \subseteq K_{n}$. Then $$\bigcap K_{n}$$ is non empty.

If I was to know that $X$ is first countable then it would imply $X$ is sequentially compact then I can prove the statement.

My question is without knowing it is first countable or not. How to prove it purely with compactness. Or is the statement true for non first countable spaces?

I know compact Hausdorff spaces are normal  but it also doesn't imply first countabilty. And there are compact Hausdorff non first countable spaces etc.

Comment: Now I notice that:

Using cantor's theorem would be enough? Since each $K_n$ would be compact nested sets?

Comment: Take complements. If $\bigcap_nK_n=\emptyset$, then $\{X\setminus K_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is an open cover of $X$ (in Hausdorff spaces, compact sets are open) and son and so forth.

Comment: If $X$ is only assumed to be sequentially compact, it is in particular countably compact and this statement would also be true (regardless of being first countable or not) because the proof by @Emo only uses a countable cover of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

As @Oliver Diaz mentioned in the comment, if $\bigcap_n K_n=\emptyset$, then $\mathcal{U}=\{ X\backslash K_n\vert n\in \mathbb{N} \}$ would've been a cover for $X$ for which $X\backslash K_n\subseteq X\backslash K_{n+1}, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, hence there is no finite subcover for $\mathcal{U}$ which contradicts the condition of compactness of the space $X$.